# Why my UIButtons aren't displayed inside my containers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a view containing 13 `UIButton`. They are all using auto layout. Among those buttons are 3 buttons acting like containers as I want to make a flip transition on them to display different buttons if the 13th button is pressed. The layout is fine for the containers.

So in viewDidLoad I create 6 buttons. 3 are added as subviews to the containers (the 3 others will be switched to the 3 first through `UIView.transitionFromView` if the 13th button is pressed).

My code to create the buttons is the following:

```
func createCalculatorButton(title: String, frame: CGRect, color: UIColor, action: Selector) -> UIButton {
    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    button.frame = frame
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    button.setBackgroundImage(GraphicHelper.imageBackground(color), forState: .Normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: action, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return button
}
```

The `frame` used is the frame of each 3 containers.

When I run the app, instead of having them in the containers, they are positioned in coordinates `(0.0,0.0)`, in the left corner of the phone (in the status bar).

I don't understand why as I added the buttons in the containers through `addSubView` and the frame of each button is the same as its container.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the `frame` passed it – is it correct? Also, you say you're using auto layout but you're setting the frame directly. Where are the auto layout constraints?

Comment: Yes indeed I had to use the auto layout. I thought that as the view was inside a view using the auto layout, I didn't need to use auto layout for this one as I wanted to fill it up. But in the end, the frame wasn't properly set as it's using auto layout so I had to use auto layout for my inner view. Thanks anyway. I'll try to post an answer with the code just in case if it helps someone else with the same problem.